# What is the most proper way of wiring RJ45 for Cat6/LAN?

Tags: ethernet, cable, cat6, rj45

I currently know of three different wiring patterns for RJ45: T568A, T568B, and USOC.

Simply put: ***Which is the best method for creating a Cat6 cable?***

From my research, it seems like I should use T568B, however I am not aware of any advantages for doing so. Is the "recommended standard" even on my (tiny) list above?

If it needs to be known: I am in the United States.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAN connections should be wired with T568A or T568B.  The only significant difference is the green and orange the pairs are switched between the two standards. T568B is a revision of T568A, and either should work.   Both ends of each cable must use the same standard.  However, you can mix and match cables using both standards.

USOD appears to be be a multi-line telephone cabling standard for 3 or 4 lines.  It is not suitable for data use.

The T568 standards can be used for two lines on the center four pins without splitting pairs.  However lines 3 and 4 would be split across pairs which may cause problems.